# Запись в текстовый файл и считывание

Tags: python, файлы

У меня есть файл, куда я записываю информацию в следующем виде:
`228695396 +79163254721`

Мне необходимо проверять файл записывать в переменную левую и правую часть. Далее эти переменные будут проверять с другими переменными. Как можно записывать и считывать нужные данные и какой для этого нужен цикл?

Comment: Не лучше ли сразу с базой данных работать? :)

Comment: Это элементарная задача, посмотрите примеры какие-нибудь по чтению/записи файлов, ну и функцию `split`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как понимаю Ваш вопрос больше про расстановку данных в файле.

```py
t = ""
# читаем файл и записываем в список t
with open("file.txt", mode="r") as f:
    text = f.read()
    t = text.split()
# например меняем первую пару
t[0] = "Hello"
t[1] = "World"

# Переписываем файл с новыми данными
i = 0 # определяем четное поле или нет
with open("file.txt", mode="w") as f:
    for a in t:
        if i % 2 != 0: # если НЕ четное то заканчивам переходом на новую строку
            f.write(a+"\n")
        else: # если четное то заканчивам пробелом
            f.write(a+" ")
        i+=1
```

P.S. А если серьезно то ерунда все это. Для хранения таких данных посмотрите в строну словарей и json.
Если данных много то возможно стоит подумать про базу данных.

Answer (score 0):

```
# если числа лежат в файле numbers.txt

with open("numbers.txt") as f:
     num_left, num_right = f.read().split()

# в num_left окажется правое число, в num_right - левое
# дальше можно творить с ними то, что хочется
# если строк много то надо определиться со структурой, 
# в которую надо сложить значения.
# строка одна в файле предполагается?
```